# WCF Teseract error: Attempted to read or write protected memory... on exe works fine

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I use teseract v2 to OCR image, it's work fine in exe, but when i try to do it on WCF everythime i get this exception:

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted.**

The same code over exe (work) and wcf (exception):

```
var processor = new TesseractProcessor();

processor.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", Metadata.TextRegexPattern);
processor.Init(@"../../tessdata/" + Language + ".traineddata", Language, 3);
processor.SetPageSegMode(_pageSegmentationMode);
processor.AnalyseLayout(source);

return processor.Recognize(Image.FromFile(filePath)); // here's problem with recognize method
```

Comment: What is your filePath? Is it not different depending on the component using it (whether it's the exe or the web service)?